# ¿ Como asignar a una variable string los estilos de un fichero CSS en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Necesito crear una función llamada recogerEstilo para pasar a una variable string todo un fichero CSS y asi cambiar con el contenido de esa variable los estilos a un elemento HTML.

```
cssString = recogerEstilo(miEstilo.css);
var objetoEstilos = document.getElementById(idObjeto).style.cssText = cssString;
document.body.style.cssText = objetoEstilos;
```

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: No se si hay alguna  función tipo <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/miEstilo.css"> para en vez de cargar el CSS en el documento lo cargue en una variable tipo String